# Alternate for Chatter Blacklist

Tags: appexchange

I have installed  Chatter Blacklist. but it was failed. I just want to prevent the words while posting in Chatter post.

Can you find me an alternative Appexchange APP for Chatter Blacklist. I got the issue while installing in Production.

Comment: I have provided the additional details.